# Tip Calculator - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem with my app. I am trying to get 15% of what is entered in a textbox to show up in a label after a push of a button. Here is my code so far:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    var fifteenPercent: Double
    fifteenPercent = 0.15
    var billTop = billTextField.text.toInt()!
    var billTipped: Double
    billTipped = Double(billTop) * fifteenPercent

    tipAmountLabel.text = "$\(billTipped)"
```

When I start the app and push the button, I get the error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Comment: May I know what is your xcode version

Comment: xcode version: Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is unwrapping the string to an int, try getting it this way:

```
var billTop = (billTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Smells like your `billTextField` doesn't have it's IBOutlet hooked up. You're forcing the unwrap of the `text` in `billTextField`. If that's nil it will blow up.

Comment: sadly it does, as of now im really confused

Answer (score 0):

Add like this:

```
 var billTop = Int(txt_address.text!)
tipAmountLabel.text =  String(format:"$%.2f", billTipped)
```